# Contacts showing as "Unknown name" on Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: contacts, samsung, sync, samsung-galaxy-s-6

As per the below image contacts sync'd from online servcies are coming through as "Unknown name"

I have used the contacts sync within "Accounts" using Gmail, Outlook.com and Yahoo but keep getting the same behaviour with the resultant contacts.  What is causing it?

[image: Contacts apps]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: http://goodpkb.force.com/PublicKnowledgeBase/articles/Answer/17203 this is the problem apparently, in having the same issue, and i'm looking forward to fix it.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with my Galaxy S6 - started roughly 1 Sept 2016 - after the SAMSUNG software/firmware update. Until then, I had no problems at all with my phone, which I bought in spring 2015. In the last two days I spent 40 minutes with a Verizon tech rep and an hour with a SAMSUNG 'tech rep' via live chat. They suggested that my device had certain problems. But I am sending email to SAMSUNG weekly to ask for an explanation. [edited my Moderator Firelord].